# Stopping text short of righthand side ``date'' column in -res- class?

Tags: margins, cv, resume

I am using the res class to make a CV (I know its outdated; path dependency)
I would like to have all the dates on the righthand side in a column of their own (with no text running under the dates like in the example below).

Please see the minimal document below. How can we get the text to stop say 0.5cm left of ``Summer 1985''?

Thank you!

```
% LaTeX file for resume 
% This file uses the resume document class (res.cls)

\documentclass{res}

\textwidth=5.5in % increase textwidth to get smaller right margin


\newsectionwidth{5pt} 

\begin{document} 




 {\bf Consultant,} National Money Bank USA, Melville, NY \hfill Summer  1985
 \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt  % reduce space between items
 \item Created regression model to lower check volume 
                 forecast errors Created model to lower check volume 
                 forecast errors Created regression model to lower check volume 
                 forecast errors
 \end{itemize}

 {\bf Consultant,} National Money Bank USA, Melville, NY \hfill Summer  1985

Created regression model to lower check volume 
                 forecast errors Created regression model to lower check volume 
                 forecast errors Created regression model to lower check volume 
                 forecast errors



\end{document}
```

Comment: As reference, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and/or
[Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option to obtain the output you're after. Without more information on its usage, it should be sufficient:

[image]

```
\documentclass{res}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% \newitem{<what>}{<where>}{<when>}{<description>}
\newcommand{\newitem}[4]{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X l @{}}
    \textbf{#1}, #2 & #3 \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    #4
  \end{tabularx}}
\begin{document}

\newitem{Consultant}{National Money Bank USA, Melville, NY}{Summer 1985}{%
  Created regression model to lower check volume forecast errors Created model to lower check volume 
  forecast errors Created regression model to lower check volume forecast errors
}

\newitem{Consultant}{National Money Bank USA, Melville, NY}{Summer 1985}{%
  Created regression model to lower check volume forecast errors Created model to lower check volume 
  forecast errors Created regression model to lower check volume forecast errors
}

\end{document}
```